# Mapping variables in json output to position in string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

How do I map the `example` in the json output to a string based on the `position`? It's rather difficult to explain, but I have included my code and further details below:

**JSON output**

```
[
    {
        "phrase": "Training {{group}} to develop their {{attribute}} by ensuring they are comfortable with {{factor}}",
        "example": "the team",
        "position": 0
    },
    {
        "phrase": "Training {{group}} to develop their {{attribute}} by ensuring they are comfortable with {{factor}}",
        "example": "match skills",
        "position": 1
    },
    {
        "phrase": "Training {{group}} to develop their {{attribute}} by ensuring they are comfortable with {{factor}}",
        "example": "defence techniques",
        "position": 2
    }
]
```

**controller.js**

```
PhraseService.getPhraseExample($scope.phraseId).then(function(dataResponse) {
  $scope.phraseExampleList = dataResponse.data;
})
```

**services.js**

```
function PhraseService($http) {

  this.getPhraseExample = function(phraseId) {

    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: server + '/api/phrase-example/' + phraseId,
    });

  }

}
```

**phrase-detail.html**

```
<div class="item item-text-wrap">
    <span ng-repeat="e in phraseExampleList">{{ e }}</span>
</div>
```

**Current output**

[image]

**Desired output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18234317/3856625 Seems that StackOverflow has the same method you need :)

So you would map over the entries you have and just use it to replace the needed.